# Specifying worksheet name required when identifying a cell by name in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-access, vba

I don't know if this is a change in the version, but in 2003 this used to work in Access VBA:

```
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
xlSheet.Range("RangeName").Value = 100
```

Previously I did not need to identify the worksheet because "RangeName" was unique. Is Excel 2007 not considering this a unique value and requires that the worksheet be specified?

[EDIT] Here is the error in Access 2007 VBA:  "Error 1004 (Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed." Trying to avoid naming the worksheet.

I used the Name Manager in Excel. The name is unique and the scope is workbook.

[image]

When I tried to Edit Name, it does not allow the scope to be changed.
[image]

Note: This workbook is Template that allows macros and the names are a mess.

Comment: Where to you assign the worksheets?  Like Set xlSheet = ...

Comment: @dkusleika - Although for this line of code that would work, I prefer not to since I'm referencing a Workbook level name and I'm doing this more than once.

Comment: Maybe I didn't say that right.  You have an xlSheet variable but you don't set it to anything.  Based on the code you show, xlSheet would be Nothing.  You should get an error 91 for that, but I'm just trying to understand your code.

Comment: @dkusleika - My guess is prior to Office 2007, this object was defaulted to the worksheet of the Name Label. Now the scope can be set at the worksheet level which would allow duplicate Name Label values and limit Excel 2007's ability to apply a default worksheet.

Comment: Is the worksheet a member of a collection that can be addressed by index?

Answer (score 1):

Is RangeName definitely a unique range and defined as a Global name, not Local to one or more worksheets?

Jan Karel Pietersen's Name Manager is a great free tool for viewing, managing and editing names which may help sort out if this is an issue with the name rather than the code.

http://www.jkp-ads.com/officemarketplacenm-en.asp

Comment: Thanks for listing Name Manager. I'm going to try the one in Excel 2007 first.